# Is comma needed before "and" in two connecting clauses?

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions, commas

I have the fallowing sentence (I've changed the content to keep it fairly understandable, the relations between the parts are the same).

> However, it states in the literature that green people love apples, which strengthens the idea that at least some green people would buy apples **and** that by opening a chain of apple stores great profits can be made.

I'm not sure if I should leave it as is, add a comma before the emphasized "and" or make the part after the "and" into a new sentence.

Comment: It seems grammatically valid to me as-is; it's a bit long and unwieldy, so breaking it up is not a bad idea - but not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @MT_Head, Could you offer how to break it up. Sadly the original sentence is much longer, and it's far from my longest one. :(

Comment: @IlyaMelamed: Change "_at least some green people would buy apples and that by opening a chain of apple stores_..." to "_at least some green people would buy apples.  Therefore, by opening a chain of apple stores, great profits can be made_."

Comment: I'll take an author who's not afraid of long sentences over one whose bible is the Turkey City Lexicon any day. The sentence is fine as it is; if the flow isn't forced and if it makes contextual sense to keep it together, don't separate _just_ because you've hit some artificial word limit.

Comment: @aaamos - I'd never heard of the [Turkey City Lexicon](http://www.critters.org/turkeycity.html), but - having given it a read - I definitely wish that more authors used it as their bible, or at least their Ten Commandments ('Thou shalt not write trite, cliched crap and inflict it upon the world.')  Not sure what your issue with it is - did they single out a particular tic of yours?  Although I _do_ get a bit tired of conscious "eyeball kicks"...

Comment: @MT_Head: Oh, they have many valid points, but as with so many things, people tend to take it to such extremes that they'll pounce on anyone using "replied" instead of "said", for instance, rather than getting what the original criticism was about. (Five monkeys in a cage scenario.) If you have common sense and never read the TCL, you haven't missed anything. My point here was that you shouldn't follow some rule for the sake of following a rule.

Comment: I would break it up as follows.  Note also how I've reversed the bit at the end; this feels more natural to me.  "However, it states in the literature that green people love apples.  This strengthens the idea that at least some green people would buy apples and that great profits can be made by opening a chain of apple stores."

Comment: @aaamos - I see what you mean about slavish devotion to a rulebook; the crucial missing ingredient is the "common sense" of which you so casually speak (as if it weren't rare and precious!) My rule for splitting up sentences, though, has nothing to do with word count and everything to do with how hard you're making the reader work to understand you.  I think I'm a fairly perceptive and careful reader; if I have to go back to the beginning to remind myself of the point, the sentence is just too darn long.  Of course this rule only applies when clarity is desirable; disregard for academe.

Comment: @MT_Head: True, and valid point about overly long sentences being hard to understand. I just don't think this one was anywhere near overly long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between two independent clauses, a comma is common before *and,* but since these are both subordinate clauses attached to *idea,* I would avoid the comma, which suggests a separation that isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

"Comma before and" is a style issue, which is frowned upon by certain style guides.

However, I personally encourage its judicious use to disambiguate and to improve readability.

In your example, the sentence in any case is too long and begs to be divided into smaller ones. The real issue here therefore, is not the comma.

Answer (score -4):

Placing a comma after a conjunction is a style used by me and those whose styles I have imitated, to compel the reader to pause in expectation before continuing with reading the rest of the sentence.

To me the effect is like pulling the rubber band of the catapult back and then releasing it:

> Not only did she destroy all the books in the library but, she even pointed her fingers at me implying that I had done it.

> She was the brightest, the most charming star of the evening and, she was the sweetest angel I had ever met. And, her name is Betty White.

Comment: -1. Sorry, but this is neither what the OP is asking nor good practice. If you really want to force a pause _after_ the conjunction, consider using a colon, but a comma is not appropriate here.

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaahhh!

Comment: "nor good practice"? You people are obviously no fan of Hemingway.